# How can I get the latest messages in Discord without using Discord Bot?

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I want to create a program that can send and receive messages in Discord without logging into my account. I have created the sending mechanism and the UI but I don't know how to create the receiving mechanism. I don't want to use some confusing mechanism that uses the Discord.py bot on Google. Can anyone help me retrieve messages without Discord.py or if yes, please explain clearly

This is my code (it runs clearly):

```py
import requests
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import json

#* UI system

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Python Discord message sender")
window.geometry("400x250+500+250")

group_frame = tk.Frame(window, width=400, height=115)
group_frame.pack()

group_lb = tk.Label(group_frame, text="Choose group: ", font=("Sans-serif", 13))
group_lb.place(x=130, y=20)

choices = list(json.load(open("urls.json")).keys())

groups = ttk.Combobox(group_frame, values=choices, state="readonly", font=("Sans-serif", 13))
groups.place(x=130, y=50)

msg_frame = tk.Frame(window, width=400, height=135)
msg_frame.pack()

msg_lb = tk.Label(msg_frame, text="Type message to this server: ", font=("Sans-serif", 13))
msg_lb.place(x=100, y=0)

msg_entry = tk.Entry(msg_frame, border=3, width=40, font=("Sans-serif", 13))
msg_entry.place(x=10, y=30)

#* Message sending system

urls = json.load(open("urls.json"))

auths = json.load(open("auths.json"))

header = auths['me']

def send():
    group_sending = groups.get()
    if group_sending == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error!", "You have not chosen a group to send to! Try again")
    message = msg_entry.get()
    if not message == "":
        content = {
            "content": message
        }

        try:
            res = requests.post(urls[group_sending], content, headers=header)
            if res.status_code == 200:
                messagebox.showinfo("Sending info", "Successfully sent message")
                msg_entry.delete(0, "end")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("ERROR!", f"An error occurred while sending the message, try again. \n \n Error code: {res.status_code}")
        except Exception as bug:
            if str(bug):
                messagebox.showerror("ERROR!", "An error occurred while sending the message, try again. \n \n Error: No connection")
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("ERROR!", f"An error occurred while sending the message, try again. \n \n Error: {bug}")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error!", "You have not written a message to this group!, Try again")
    

msg_submit = tk.Button(msg_frame, text="Send message", font=("Sans-serif", 13), command=send)
msg_submit.place(x=130, y=60)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: as I remeber `Discord` doesn't allow to use `user account` in code. They may delete your account. You should use special account for bot.

Comment: probably to do it you would have to create code similar to `discord.py`. And you would have to read API documentation to see how to connect to account, and use `requests` to send or receive information. Eventually it may need to run something like `web server` and `discord server` will send information to this server.

Comment: But I can't send messages directly from the bot account. If there is a way, please guide me.

Comment: as I said `Discord` doesn't allow to use `user account` in code :) And bot also can't work as `user account` :) maybe because this can be used by spamers and hackers - to automate attacks.

Comment: So you mean I can't chat without logging into my account?